# Codeigniter userdata lost after session id refresh [CodeIgniter 3.0]

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

Im using the Session Library of Codeigniter on my Website connected to a MySQL Database.
I have my own Library that works with the session wich is created to handel the login check.

Basically when i log in i store that i'm logged in, in the userdata from the session cookie. (then there are other checks to have some sort of security)

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in','1');
```

Now as soon as the session id gets refreshed (standard 300 seconds) all my userdata is gone. I cheked in the Database and there the session Id is not getting updated it just creates a new one.

I'm using the Codeigniter 3.0 and im not sure if thats supposed to work like that.

Edit:

my config.php (session stuff)

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

cookie Stuff

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Basically what happens ist the following thing:

I get the Session with the id 123. I assign the userdata logged_in = 1 to the session.
All is saved in the DB.
After 5 minutes. (Or the Time defined in the config file)

```
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

I get in my Browser a new session with the id 137 without the userdata.
The Session 123  with the userdata logged_ind = 1 is still in the database, together with the newly created session 137.

So instead of an update "sess_time_to_update" its more creation of a new session.

Comment: can you provide your session settings found in `config.php` ?

Comment: Check out the value of your `sess_expiration` value in your `application/config/config.php` file

Comment: According to here : http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#how-do-sessions-work
"If a sessions cookie does not exist (or if it doesn’t match one stored on the server or has expired) a new session will be created and saved." So if there is a problem with the cookie, it is supposed to a new session instead of updating. If you just want to change expiration, follow the lead of @SolarBear. However, I suggest you to code your own session class if you need something specific.

Comment: @CodeGodie i edited the post.  Süha Boncukçu thats right but the session id still exist in the db (i double checked that, so why does it create a new one?)

Answer (score 0):

your session keeps expiring, change these settings:

From:

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
```

To:

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200; // expires in 2 hours
```

Comment: ok trying that atm. But in the description it says : "The number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
Setting to 0 (zero) means expire when the browser is closed." And ive never closed the browser?

Comment: Ok i tried it, it dosent work :( every 5 minutes it still creates a new Session.

Comment: hey im back. I see what you mean now.. tell me more about your desired design. From what I understand, you have an application, where you set the expiration to 0 ( so that it expires on close), but you keep losing your userdata.. do you lose your userdata on a specific page? or does it happen on different pages?

Comment: So i think the problem is, that the codeigniter session library, (out of some reason i dont know) creates every 5 minutes a new session. It does not reuse the one in the db and stuff. Whenever it creates a new session all the userdata is obviousely lost.

Comment: yea theres something wrong there.. I am trying it here, with the following settings `$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 30;` but it does not fail. it refreshes, but does not lose userdata

Comment: below you `sess` configs, you will see your `cookie` config settings in `config.php`, what do you see there?

Comment: i added the sess configs to the main question. do you know where the refresh happens in the session library? (i cant find it) so i can try to find out why he creates a new one :)

Comment: thats a tough task to take.. I just don't see why your session keeps deleting the userdata which essentially is the BLOB stored in your `ci_sessions` table, if you have all the settings correct. When did you download CI 3.0? maybe it was an issue on their release since its new, try to re install it.

Comment: yes i know :P  the session is not deleting the userdata, its still in the blob in the ci_sessions table!!!!!  I Update the Question to explain it better.

Comment: if i set `$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;` it affects all session userdata, how can i expire particular userdata after 1000 seconds.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. You should only have one userdata per session, not many.